# Trying to run my first ruby test through Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have successfully installed Appium and I have updated the following ruby gems:

$ gem update --system
$ gem update bundler

and installed the following gems for ruby:

gem uninstall -aIx appium_lib
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri appium_lib

Here is my first ruby test:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'

APP_PATH = appAddress 

desired_caps = {
    caps: {
        platformName:  iOS,
        platformVersion: 11.4,
        deviceName:    iPhone 7,
        app:           APP_PATH,
        automationName: XCUITest,
    },
    appium_lib: {
        sauce_username:   nil,
        sauce_access_key: nil,
        wait: 60
    }
}

# Start the driver
Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps, true).start_driver

module DataSiteOne
    module iOS

    #prints statement
    puts "Entered into this test!"

    #Quit when you're done!
    driver_quit
    puts "First Tests Succeeded!"

    end
end
```

I am getting the following error message after I start up appium from terminal and then run the my first ruby test.

```
require 'rubygems'
        ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I had written my tests in javascript hence I was using the following command:

Node "your project name"

Once you startup appium in terminal then run the following command to run your ruby test files: 
ruby "fileName"